# Does any Jewish group follow Yerushalmi only?

Tags: communities, talmud-yerushalmi

Does any Jewish group follow Yerushalmi over Bavli? Thank you.

Comment: Check out http://machonshilo.org/ but I don't know if you would classify them as a "group". You might also want to look into the Romaniote Jews https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romaniote_Jews

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Interested, and thanks for the interesting question! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us. And if you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: what do you mean "follow"?

Comment: Interesting question! You could make this question clearer by [edit]ing in information about the norm and why you are interested to know about deviations from it.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that some italian jews follow it to a small extent, and some scholars of the yerushalmi later traveled the bavel (And visa versa), but nobody follows it exclusively. Before the crusades, there were some very vibrant communities who followed the Yerushalmi exclusively, especially in the north in teveriah. When the crusaders came in, they saw them not as people, but as infidels, and returned them to the Creator through bloodshed. The last community survived in Cairo until the days of the Rambam, but less and less people were showing up. in the end, by the fifteenth century, no-one was of yerushalmi tradition. These days, some people have become increasingly interested in the customs of the yerushalmi.